# Manipulating attributes from a namedtuple() derived class

Tags: python, inheritance, namedtuple, attr-protected

I have a class called `EasyUrl()` that is derived from `urlparse.Parseresult()`. `ParseResult()` is instantiated when calling `urlparse.urlparse(url)`, I have a static method inside `EasyUrl()` that changes the class type of the instantiated `ParseResult()` object into a `EasyUrl()` object. I wrap the `urlparse.urlparse()` function and the class type conversion into a function `parse_url()`.

The reason behind such a function, is my attempt to hack around a separate problem I don't require an answer to but would like one, is I get a `TypeError` when `__new__` is called during the instantiating process, which lets me know I have an invalid number of arguments.

#### Error received when instantiating `EasyUrl()` directly

```
# snippet 
url = 'stackoverflow.com'
url = EasyUrl(url)
# snippet end

Output:
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 7 arguments (2 given)
```

The `ParseResult()` class inherits from a `namedtuple()`.

#### Excerpt from urlparse library

```
class ParseResult(namedtuple('ParseResult', 'scheme netloc path params query fragment'), ResultMixin):

    __slots__ = ()

    def geturl(self):
        return urlunparse(self)
```

Now that I have described a little functionality of the code, here is the problem. I can't access the named tuple's (ParseResult) attributes. I'm trying to implement a default scheme for `ParseResult()` if it is missing.

But I can't access the attributes in the class definition.

```
import urlparse


def parse_url(url):
    """ Return a parsed EasyUrl() object"""
    parse_result = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    return EasyUrl.EvolveParseResult(parse_result)


class EasyUrl(urlparse.ParseResult):

    @staticmethod
    def EvolveParseResult(parse_result):
        """ Change the type of class into a EasyUrl() Object."""
        parse_result.__class__ = EasyUrl
        easy_url = parse_result # For readabilty
        easy_url.init()
        return easy_url

    def __init__(self, url):
        self = parse_url(url) # doesn't work

    def init(self):
        self.url = self.geturl()
        #self.set_scheme_if_non() # Uncomment when no error is raised

    def set_scheme_if_non(self, scheme='http'):
        if not self.scheme:
            self.scheme = scheme
            self.url = self.geturl() # Rebuild our url with the new scheme



# Passes the set_scheme_if_non trigger
#url = 'https://stackoverflow.com'
# Fails if statment, then attempts to set the variable,
# but error is raised: AttributeError: can't set attribute
url = 'stackoverflow.com'

# Will give the error: TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 7 arguments (2 given)
#url = EasyUrl(url)

# works fine, I don't know why. Except that I can't access
# the tuples attributes in the class definition
url = parse_url(url) 

print url.scheme # Works fine

url.set_scheme_if_non() # Raises an error
```

#### Output

```
File "/home/crispycret/easyurl.py", line 50, in <module>
  url.set_scheme_if_non() # Raises an error
File "/home/crispycret/easyurl.py", line 29, in set_scheme_if_non
  self.scheme = scheme

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: FYI, I know that because I'm changing the class after initiation the `EasyUrl.__init__()` is never called, when creating an  `EasyUr()` object from the `parse_url()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a new class from scratch and transfer all the attributes from `ParseResult` over?

```
import urlparse

class EasyURL(object):
    def __init__(self, parse_result):
        self.scheme = parse_result.scheme
        self.netloc = parse_result.netloc
        self.path = parse_result.path
        self.params = parse_result.params
        self.query = parse_result.query
        self.fragment = parse_result.fragment

    @classmethod
    def from_url(cls, url):
        return cls(urlparse.urlparse(url))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'http://foo.bar.com:8888/path/to/script.php?a=1&b=2'

    # Call from_url class method, which is very convenient
    easy_url = EasyURL.from_url(url)

    # Or, do it yourself
    easy_url = EasyURL(urlparse.urlparse(url))
```

You can now add any additional method to this class as desired.

## Update

- `namedtuple` is a function that creates a new type on the fly. By the way, our `EasyURL` object will not act as a tuple unless we add some code for `__getitem__()`
- `ParseResult` does not allow you to change your attributes such as `scheme`, so there is no reason to inherit from it.

Comment: I was transferring the variables at first, but wanted to try to simplify the code by using inheritance, but it got more complicated.

Comment: Thanks, for the decorator tip, I'll definitely  use it, as well as the code. I also just looked at the type of a namedtuple() and it's a function, so I'm guessing that it's returning a list, which would make sense that I cant access the variable. But the leaves the question of why an instance can do so and not the class definition. I guess it's just some Python Magic!

Comment: `namedtuple` is a function that creates a new type on the fly. By the way, our `EasyURL` object will not act as a tuple unless we add some code for `__getitem__()`.

Comment: Cool, I need to go through the python built-in object methods for each type again.